# Docker edge portal

Tags: docker

I'm learning docker and wanted to know if there is a way to manage docker containers using a web portal (not Kubernetes) for a local test environment. I searched online and could not  find any info.

Please help me with the installation procedure of the same

Thanks for your help in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following ones:

- https://github.com/shipyard/shipyard
- https://kitematic.com/
- https://github.com/francescou/docker-compose-ui
- https://microbadger.com
- http://portainer.io/
- https://dockstation.io/
- http://rancher.com/rancher

And the Credit goes to: https://blog.codeship.com/docker-guis/